# Gitlab- file history contains commit, but file is not updated in repo

Tags: git, gitlab

We updated a file in October 2022, and we can see in this file's file history that there was a commit on 10/9/2022 and see the updated file when browsing files for that commit, but in the repo, the file still says last updated in September 2021 and is out of date. There have been no other commits since the one on 10/9/2022, and no reverts, so why is the file outdated in the repo, but not in the commit? Is it possible to have a revert without any record of it?

The file is out of date on both branches and both were updated the same day, so this isn't a mistaken branch.

Comment: Git isn't about *files*, it's about *commits*. Every commit contains a full snapshot of every file. So the latest commit has the latest version of every file. When you see a view that claims some file was changed "on <insert date here>", that's GitHub or GitLab (in this case GitLab) doing a search for the earliest appearance of that file. If the file looks the way it does now (and it does), obviously whoever made the *last* commit used that version. The version in the Oct 2022 commit doesn't matter *unless* you specifically check out that Oct 2022 commit.

Comment: You might (and I would) disagree with the way GitLab is showing this date, but in the end, that's not really relevant. It's just a bug (my opinion here) in the way GitLab is finding a date stamp to show you. They probably should just show you the date stamp of the latest commit: that would be much less useful, but it wouldn't be *wrong* either. :-)

Comment: Anyway, the point here is that the files in the commit literally *can't* be *wrong*. They're whatever is in the commit. That's all there is to it. If you don't like the file(s) in that commit, make another commit with different files in it. That's pretty much all Git gives you here.